# Wait until element is not present

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium in Python 2.7 and I have this code, but I'm looking for a more efficient way to do this:

```
while True:
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'button'))
        )   
    except:
        break
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'button')))
```

you don't need to use while. it already waits for time that you present in WebDriverWait() function.

Comment: I want the opposite, when the element is not present.

Comment: you mean, you want to wait for element become invisible/unpresent?

Comment: invisibility of element is a bit different from presence of element, so this is not a precise answer to this question. The above is an answer to a different but very similar question about invisibility.

Comment: A closing bracket ")" is missing from the function.

Comment: I would add try/except to this code. What if an element is not present? There will be  StaleElementReferenceException

Answer (score 10):

1) Use staleness_of from expected condition

```
class staleness_of(object):
""" Wait until an element is no longer attached to the DOM.
element is the element to wait for.
returns False if the element is still attached to the DOM, true otherwise.
"""
```

2) WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(...)