# Timeout in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have to add stopwatch to my script

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

start = time.clock()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://ebay.com')
```

after this code it should stay for a while(5 seconds), than do other staff, like this:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
element.send_keys("some text")
```

How to do it?

Comment: You need to use [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) then, which will wait until element present.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur I found "until". Can i use it like, Until appearing element_by_id("username"). Can you show how to do it, please

Comment: there are many example around it, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26566799/selenium-python-how-to-wait-until-the-page-is-loaded) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717334/wait-until-element-is-not-present)..Thanks

Comment: @NurislomTuraev Why do you want to wait for 5 secs? How about providing the `username` as soon as the field is available?

Comment: @DebanjanB Because I want to use it on many websites, even where has cloudflare protection. So thats why I need it.

Comment: Wouldn't providing the "username" as soon as the `username` field is available to be filled up, suffice to your needs? Thanks

Comment: @DebanjanB This problem is related to another website, but I can't show it. There are some my private deal with that page. So I need stopwatch until appears some fields. This is a problem. Have any ideas?

Comment: Okay, I understand your problem. But I am double mined now. Without any visibility to your Business Case it sounds like `time.sleep(n)` is the solution which is against all Best Practices. But again how can you conclude that `5 seconds` thresh-hold will suffice in all of your cases? Thanks

Comment: I solved problem. Thank you to everybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent many hours and with help of God and many people from StackOverflow, I finally solved it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(''https://ebay.com'')
delay = 30

try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
    element.send_keys("some text")
except TimeoutException:
    print ("Loading took too much time!")
```

It would be the best, in my opinion.