# About selenium isvisible

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

When I was using selneium I found a problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DlUE.jpg)
as the picture shows

How can I tell if this loading element has disappeared?

Because it causes me to click on the element in the form, it will give an error: the element cannot click。

Can I use invisibility_of_element_located to determine if the loading element has disappeared

Comment: show us your code and tell us which element you want to click in that image

Comment: You need to create a locator that finds the loader and then wait for it to be invisible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until element is not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32717334/wait-until-element-is-not-present)

Answer (score -1):

Use below code to check , it will help you to check if the element is displayed or not

```
if( driver.findElement(By.xpath("any xpath")).isDisplayed()){
System.out.println("Element is Visible");
}else{
System.out.println("Element is InVisible");
}
```